# Obter diretório geral do projeto, php

Tags: php

Como pode se fazer para obter a raiz da pasta do projeto com PHP?

Minhas pesquisas mandam eu usar **DIR** entretanto essa retorna a direção dependendo da localização do arquivo, e eu quero a raiz do projeto, muito chamada de www, htdocs etc...

Supondo essa organização

www/
  outrapasta/
    outrapasta/
      Índex.php

Independentemente de onde o arquivo está localizado, eu quero sempre obter o diretório da www..

Comment: Utiliza o **$_SERVER['DOCUMEN_ROOT']**, e cria uma constante **DIR** com base nesse endereço.

Comment: Se você for utilizar no terminal `$_SERVER['DOCUMEN_ROOT']` virá vazio. Porém como você tá falando que quer a raiz do documento, então subentende-se que você quer usar via servidor web.
Sugiro então que você crie uma constante que aponte para o diretório raiz, no inicio do código, ou no arquivo de configuração da tua aplicação. Assim em qualquer arquivo posterior você terá esta constante disponível.
A constante funcionará tanto pra chamadas via linha de comando como pra chamadas via servidor web.

Answer (score 4):

Como já havia explicado, utiliza variável `$_SERVER`, não deves esperar que todos os navegadores/sistemas retornem a mesma coisa, porque alguns destes, ás vezes omitem informações, mas o que digo é que, utiliza esta variável apenas para descobrir qual é o diretório **root** que estás a atualmente a utilizar ou vais utilizar, utilizando diretamente essa variável ou baseando-se apenas no caminho que ela retornar.

Na *consola/terminal* de comandos, evidentemente não vai retornar o caminho, mas se executares à partir de um navegador vais conseguir visualizar esse caminho, que por acaso é um caminho definido no ficheiro de configuração do servidor.

Num sistema *linux* recente, vais obter `/var/www/meu_site`, utilizando `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

Tendo isto como base, podes simplesmente definir todos os possíveis caminhos para a tua aplicação, num único ficheiro de configuração, que sera(ia) chamado uma única vez.

```
// init.php
// Ficheiro de inicialização de configurações gerais
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('ROOT',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
define('SITE_ROOT',ROOT.DS.'meu_site');
# 2º alternativa
# define('SITE_ROOT',DS.'var'.DS.'www'.DS.'meu_site');
define('LIB_CLASS',SITE_ROOT.DS.'classes');
define('LIB_INCLUDES',SITE_ROOT.DS.'includes');
```

Logo, basta que incluas este ficheiro no script:

```
require_once '/includes/init.php';
// Noutros ficheiros que possuam a configuração de inicialização
print "<h3>Diretórios:</h3>";
print SITE_ROOT.DS.'teste.php';
//require_once SITE_ROOT.DS.'teste.php';
print "<br/>";
print LIB_CLASS.DS.'class.teste.php';
//require_once LIB_CLASS.DS.'class.teste.php';
print "<br/>";
print LIB_INCLUDES.DS.'testeValidar.php';
//require_once LIB_INCLUDES.DS.'testeValidar.php';
```

Os caminhos estarão assim:

```
/var/www/meu_site/teste.php
/var/www/meu_site/classes/class.teste.php
/var/www/meu_site/includes/testeValidar.php
```

> Para o windows, obviamente vais obter caminhos diferentes e
>   separadores diferentes também, mas é esta a ideia.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma isso:

```
<?php

$raiz = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

require_once $raiz . '/outrapasta/file_require_1.php';
require_once $raiz . '/outrapasta/file_require_2.php';
```

Onde a variáveis pré-definidas $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] retorna o diretório raiz sobre onde o script atual está sendo executado, como por exemplo você pode observar isso dando um var_dump nessa variável.

```
var_dump($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
```

No meu ambiente o resultado é:

```
string 'C:/xampp-1.8.2/htdocs/fypa/stackoverflow' (length=40)
```

Pelo terminal você pode pegar o diretório atual, mas não o raiz pela seguinte função:

```
<?php

echo getcwd();
```

Resuldado no meu ambiente:

```
C:\xampp-1.8.2\htdocs\fypa\stackoverflow
```

Para incluir algum arquivo:

```
<?php

$raiz = getcwd();

require_once $raiz . '/outrapasta/file_require_1.php';
```

Ou também assim, chamando dirname dentro de dirname até a raiz do seu projeto:

```
<?php

var_dump(dirname(__FILE__));

var_dump(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));

var_dump(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
```

Resultado:

```
string(40) "C:\xampp-1.8.2\htdocs\fypa\stackoverflow"
string(26) "C:\xampp-1.8.2\htdocs\fypa"
string(21) "C:\xampp-1.8.2\htdocs"
```

Comment: quando executo no terminal o valor de $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] é ""

Comment: Quando ser executar um script a partir de um arquivo no terminal não ser executa o arquivo e sim o conteúdo dele, por isso vez vazio o $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], onde não teria como ele retornar a pasta raiz sendo que ele está sendo executado como se ele tivesse sido digitado no terminal.