# Trabalhando com diretórios para fazer um require no PHP

Tags: php, mysql, require

Tenho uma página onde eu gero umas informações, armazenadas no Banco de Dados. Essa página está dentro de 5 pastas: `pasta1/pasta2/pasta3/pasta4/pasta5`.

Para o `SELECT` funcionar, preciso de um require para fazer a conexão com o banco. Esse arquivo está num diretório: `/conexao/conexao.php`.

Como posso utilizar o `require` (ou outro comando seguro) para realizar essa consulta?

Comment: procure usar caminhos absolutos. Uma forma de fazer isso é usar `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Comment: Obrigado pela pronta resposta. Tem alguma referência, para que eu possa ler?

Comment: Experimenta definir alguns directórios - http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/97525/obter-diret%C3%B3rio-geral-do-projeto-php/97545#97545

Answer (score 2):

Se estiver usando o PHP em um webserver, certamente há uma variável que informa a raiz da aplicação (ou do site) e é a partir dessa informação que você deve usar seus caminhos.

[$_SERVER](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.server.php) contém as informações relevantes do Webserver e uma delas é DOCUMENT_ROOT.

DOCUMENT_ROOT aponta para a raiz da aplicação.
Supondo que sua aplicação esteja no diretorio ***x/y/z*** (aqui não importa o sistema operacional), `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` apontará para x/y/z corretamente não importando em que nível seu script PHP esteja.

Eventualmente, por questões de segurança, costuma-se colocar arquivos que não devem ter acesso direto pelo Webserver em um caminho fora dessa árvore.
Por exemplo: Muitos Frameworks usam uma estrutura de diretórios como essa

```
-./
  -> web
  -> src
  -> test
```

Onde web será a raiz da aplicação. Nesse caso, para acessar os outros diretórios deve-se usar

```
ROOT . '/../src';
```

O [manual do PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/) é a melhor documentação de linguagem que conheço. Sempre comece suas pesquisas por lá.

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário, @Marcos. Eu vim para solicitar ajuda, pois em algumas pesquisas feitas no Google revelaram que o require não era mais tão utilizado para tal situação. Vou olhar as suas referências para tentar resolver esta questão. Assim que conseguir, posto o resultado aqui. Grande Abraço!

Comment: Tenho que discordar. A melhor documentação é a do Python :)

Comment: @OlimonF. Não conheço a documentação do Python :( . Comparo a do PHP com as que costumo usar, como Java, C#, C++ e Delphi. A melhor oficial no meu entendimento é a do PHP, mas prometo dar uma olhada na do Python. :)

Comment: @HebertRichard *require*, *include*, *require_once*, *include_once* ainda são muito utilizados. Atualmente, para aplicações que usam *autoload*, usa-se os padrões de **PSR-4** (http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) mas no final das contas, acaba-se usando *require* (https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader-examples.md)

Comment: A documentação do php em português é bem falha :p - http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/66277/3635 - mas a em inglês é bem organizada e atualizada :D

Answer (score 1):

Uma maneira alternativa a outra resposta, seria simplesmente em cada arquivo você definir o caminho relativo.

Supondo que a estrutura da pasta seja:

```
+-- ./
    +-- conexao
        +-- conexao.php
    +-- pasta1
        +-- exemplo1.php
            +-- pasta2
                +-- exemplo2.php
                    +-- pasta3
                        +-- exemplo3.php
```

No arquivo `pasta1/exemplo1.php`:

```
<?php
require '../conexao/conexao.php';
```

No arquivo `pasta1/pasta2/exemplo2.php`:

```
<?php
require '../../conexao/conexao.php';
```

No arquivo `pasta1/pasta2/pasta3/exemplo3.php`:

```
<?php
require '../../../conexao/conexao.php';
```

Você também pode criar um arquivo index.php junto com .htaccess e ele acessaria qualquer arquivo.

O arquivo deve ficar algo como .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

E o `index.php` deve ficar assim:

```
<?php
require 'conexao/conexao.php';

$pathInfo = isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']) $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] : '';
$pathInfo = ltrim($pathInfo, '/');

if (empty($pathInfo)) {
   echo 'Index normal';
} else if (is_file($pathInfo)) {
   require $pathInfo;
} else {
   header('X-PHP-Response-Code: 404', true, 404);
   echo 'Página não encontrada';
}
```